# XOR Cipher in Golang with custom base64encoding/decoding, small question regarding padding

Tags: go, encryption, base64, xor

the expected output of my code is `"IA0aB1QMAFQVRQARFxcWAFQIFgcHBBQRWg=="` however it is actually outputting `<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"IA0aB1QMAFQVRQARFxcWAFQIFgcHBBQRWgAA"`

The problem most likely is occurring in the func `customBase64Encode` but I can't wrap my head around it is the padding incorrect?

Appreciate any thoughts

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

const base64Chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"

func customBase64Encode(input []byte) string {
    var result string

    for i := 0; i < len(input); i += 3 {
        // Create a 24-bit value from three 8-bit values
        var bits uint32
        for j := 0; j < 3 && i+j < len(input); j++ {
            bits |= uint32(input[i+j]) << (8 * (2 - j))
        }

        // Break it into four 6-bit values
        for j := 0; j < 4; j++ {
            index := (bits >> ((3 - j) * 6)) & 0x3F
            result += string(base64Chars[index])
        }
    }

    // Add padding if necessary
    padding := (4 - len(result)%4) % 4
    for i := 0; i < padding; i++ {
        result += "="
    }

    return result
}

func customBase64Decode(input string) []byte {
    var result []byte

    for i := 0; i < len(input); i += 4 {
        var val uint32

        // Create a 24-bit value from four 6-bit values
        for j := 0; j < 4; j++ {
            char := input[i+j]
            index := byteIndex(char, base64Chars)
            val = val<<6 | uint32(index)
        }

        // Break it into three 8-bit values
        for j := 0; j < 3; j++ {
            result = append(result, byte((val>>(8*(2-j)))&0xFF))
        }
    }

    return result
}

func byteIndex(char byte, chars string) int {
    for i := 0; i < len(chars); i++ {
        if chars[i] == char {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}

func XOR(text string, encrypt bool, key string) string {
    // Convert the key to a byte array
    keyBytes := []byte(key)

    // If decrypting, decode the input text using custom Base64 decoding
    if !encrypt {
        decodedText := customBase64Decode(text)
        text = string(decodedText)
    }

    // Convert the text to a byte array
    textBytes := []byte(text)

    // Initialize result array
    resultBytes := make([]byte, len(textBytes))

    // Perform XOR operation
    for i := 0; i < len(textBytes); i++ {
        // Get the corresponding byte from the key, using modulo to repeat the key if necessary
        keyByte := keyBytes[i%len(keyBytes)]

        // Perform XOR
        if encrypt {
            resultBytes[i] = textBytes[i] ^ keyByte
        } else {
            // For decryption, XOR operation is the same as encryption
            resultBytes[i] = textBytes[i] ^ keyByte
        }
    }

    // If encrypting, encode the result using custom Base64 encoding
    if encrypt {
        resultText := customBase64Encode(resultBytes)
        return resultText
    }

    // If decrypting, return the result as a string
    return string(resultBytes)
}

func main() {
    // Example usage
    encryptedText := XOR("This is a secret message.", true, "test")
    fmt.Println(encryptedText) // should be "IA0aB1QMAFQVRQARFxcWAFQIFgcHBBQRWg==" but is "IA0aB1QMAFQVRQARFxcWAFQIFgcHBBQRWgAA" 

    decryptedText := XOR(encryptedText, false, "test")
    fmt.Println(decryptedText) // should be "This is a secret message." but is "This is a secret message.es"
}
```

Comment: Inside `customBase64Encode()`, the first inner loop properly goes until `j < 3 && i+j < len(input)`, but the second inner loop always adds (appends) 4 characters, even if he previous loop did not had 3 iterations. That's why you add `A`s (the first letter in alpabet) at the end, and that's why no padding will be added after that.

Comment: What's happening is that you encode the entire last 32 bit integer, and *then* add the padding up to the 4 character break. You should remember how many bits are used in the final 32 bit integer and stop adding characters in time. *Then* you should perform padding. Currently the "AA" simply represent bits not in the original byte array. They have not been set and have been left to zero in the integer.

Comment: Hint: you can also add the `=` characters in the integer. Makes encoding easier and less expensive. I'd definitely use streaming or a pre-sized buffer instead of string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't make the code work without importing "encode/base64"

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func XOR(text string, encrypt bool, key string) string {
    // Convert the key to a byte array
    keyBytes := []byte(key)

    // If decrypting, decode the input text from base64
    if !encrypt {
        decodedText, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(text)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error decoding base64:", err)
            return ""
        }
        text = string(decodedText)
    }

    // Convert the text to a byte array
    textBytes := []byte(text)

    // Initialize result array
    resultBytes := make([]byte, len(textBytes))

    // Perform XOR operation
    for i := 0; i < len(textBytes); i++ {
        // Get the corresponding byte from the key, using modulo to repeat the key if necessary
        keyByte := keyBytes[i%len(keyBytes)]

        // Perform XOR
        if encrypt {
            resultBytes[i] = textBytes[i] ^ keyByte
        } else {
            // For decryption, XOR operation is the same as encryption
            resultBytes[i] = textBytes[i] ^ keyByte
        }
    }

    // If encrypting, encode the result as base64
    if encrypt {
        resultText := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(resultBytes)
        return resultText
    }

    // If decrypting, return the result as a string
    return string(resultBytes)
}
```